# CA-SCM integration in to eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, harvest-scm

I am Using eclipse juno.I need to integrate Harvest(CA-SCM) plugin into eclipse.I followed the Harvest Documentation but CA-SCM plugin was not integrated properly in eclipse.

Anyone please guide me to integrate CA-SCM with eclipse Juno.

I'm getting the following error in CA-SCM console.

*Unable to intialize CA SCM. Please ensure that all required components are installed.*

Please help me to resolve the error.

Comment: Is there no one know the answer for the question.Please help me to resolve the error.since 4days i'm struggling to resolve this.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. not resolved yet. Some suggestions here, but they didn't help me:
http://www.ca.com/us/support/ca-support-online/product-content/knowledgebase-articles/tec595773.aspx

Comment: Even i am waiting for the answer.Right now i am using Harvest for code check-in.But i didn't try with latest eclipse version. So could you please try with  latest eclipse with CA-SCM plugin?This might resolve the issue but still i am unsure

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little late but maybe it will help anyone else with the same issue.  In order to fix this you also need to install the CA SCM Workbench (the standalone tool).  The Eclipse plugin looks for certain libraries on your PATH that are only installed with the SCM Workbench.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Actually i installed CA-SCM workbench in my PC.But i don't know how to integrate that workbench with our eclipse juno.Could you please elaborate the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved! I've got a very good answer from the Harvest guys. Those are the 3 possible reasons for the problem- check that:

1)      Are scm related variables in the beginning of the path variable?

2)      If SCM installed is 32 bit, you have to use 32 bit eclipse and if you have SCM 64 bit, you need to use 64 bit eclipse. (that was my problem)

3)      The final one is SCM plugin for eclipse should be the same version as SCM client.

The needed path variables:

are also listed here: https://docops.ca.com/ca-harvest-scm/13-0/en/installing/install-the-ca-harvest-scm-web-interface

but mainly it seems that those 3 are important:

for version 13:

SCM Home :  C:\Program Files\CA\SCM

PEC: C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\SharedComponents\PEC\bin;

If you are in r12.6 add the below one also in the beginning of PATH:

ETPKI

Restart the windows ,if possible open eclipse with a new workspace (beware of data loss)

Comment: My Eclipse version is 4.4.2 - I can't use the latest from technical reasons related to my product.

Comment: But here's the link to Harvest compatibility matrix - which Eclipse goes with what Harvest version: http://www.ca.com/us/support/ca-support-online/product-content/status/compatibility-matrix/ca-harvest-software-change-manager-v13_0-compatibility-matrix.aspx?id=%7BC604E517-AD35-4D1A-A252-EFEC7B19A046%7D